# Build tensorflow dataset with datasource as database

Tags: sql, mongodb, tensorflow

I have to create a data input pipeline with tensorflow tf.data. The datasource is a mongodb and sql server.  How can I create a tf.data object from a database. All the articles I see have .tfrecords or .csv as datasource for tensorflow.

Thank you.
Appreciate your inputs

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the data from the database and store it as a numpy array. If the array is too big for memory, try a memmap array.

Then create a generator, here is an example for images and their onehot encodings from my own code:

```
def tf_augmented_image_generator(images,
                                 onehots,
                                 batch_size,
                                 map_fn,
                                 shuffle_size=1000,
                                 num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE):
    """
    Create a generator suing a tf.data.Dataframe with augmentation via a map function.
    The generator can then be used for training in model.fit_generator

    The map function must consist of tensorflow operators (not numpy).

    On Windows machines this will lead to faster augmentation, as there are some
    problems performing augmentation in parallel when multiprocessing is enabled in
    in model.fit / model.fit_generator and the default Keras numpy-based augmentated is used,
    e.g. in ImageDataGenerator

    :param images: Images to augment
    :param onehots: Onehot encoding of target class
    :param batch_size: Batch size for training
    :param map_fn: The augmentation map function
    :param shuffle_size: Batch size of images shuffled. Smaller values reduce memory consumption.
    :param num_parallel_calls: Number of calls in parallel, default is automatic tuning.
    :return:
    """
    # Get shapes from input data
    img_size = images.shape
    img_size = (None, img_size[1], img_size[2], img_size[3])
    onehot_size = onehots.shape
    onehot_size = (None, onehot_size[1])
    images_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=img_size)
    onehots_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=onehot_size)

    # Create dataset
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images_tensor, onehots_tensor))
    if map_fn is not None:
        dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (map_fn(x), y), num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_size, reshuffle_each_iteration=True).repeat()
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)

    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    init_op = iterator.initializer
    next_val = iterator.get_next()

    with K.get_session().as_default() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op, feed_dict={images_tensor: images, onehots_tensor: onehots})
        while True:
            inputs, labels = sess.run(next_val)
            yield inputs, labels
```

Then train the model using `fit_generator`

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [TFMongoDB](https://github.com/svenboesiger/tfmongodb), a C++ implemented dataset op for Tensorflow that allows you to connect to your MongoDB.

```
dataset = MongoDBDataset("dbname", "collname")
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_line)
repeat_dataset2 = dataset.repeat()
batch_dataset = repeat_dataset2.batch(20)

iterator = iterator_ops.Iterator.from_structure(batch_dataset.output_types)
#init_op = iterator.make_initializer(dataset)
init_batch_op = iterator.make_initializer(batch_dataset)
get_next = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_batch_op, feed_dict={})

    for i in range(5):
        print(sess.run(get_next))
```